# Mp4 does not work for making videos out of frames but avi works

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the following code to create a movies out of pictures that I have and use the following code snippet:

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = 'shots'
video_name = 'video.avi'
fps = 25

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]

images = sorted(images)[:][:steps]

frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, fps, (width, height))

for image in images:
  video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

The problem is that when I change the extension to `mp4` it does not work. How can I alter my code so that I can get it to work? The reason for `mp4` is the speed of the process which is very slow and I think it is because `avi` has more quality than `mp4`.

Comment: Try to set the codec fourcc manually to mp4v. Or maybe your opencv installation is missing possible mp4 codecs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cv2.VideoWriter` syntax have `(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize)`  these parametrs you are missing one parameter called `fourcc` (fourcc: 4-character code of codec used to compress the frames)

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = 'shots'
video_name = 'video.mp4'
fps = 25

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]

images = sorted(images)[:][:steps]

frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), fps, (width, height))

for image in images:
  video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```